# How to retrieve AWS SNS Arn value

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation, amazon-sns

Im planning to use nested stack to create (SNS,ELB and application ) stacks.so
now once the sns is created i have to pass arn value to ELB and application json(cloud formation templates)so what is the resource name to get SNS arn once its created

ex:

```
"Fn::GetAtt" : [ "MyLB" , "DNSName" ]
```

similarly im looking for SNS Arn..

Answer (score 10):

In your CloudFormation template, if you simply reference your SNS topic, then you'll get the ARN.

For example:

`{ "Ref": "MySnsTopic" }`

So you can use that as input to your nested CloudFormation template.